# error while trying to add sign in with google button "RN GoogleSignin native module is not correctly linked..." - react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, google-signin

I am trying to add a sign-in button of Google, and can't understand why it doesn't work fine. after download the package react-native-google-signin, and I have also installed @react-native-community/google-sign in and these both packaged doesn't work for me. the error message: "RN GoogleSignin native module is not correctly linked..." 
code below:

```
import {  GoogleSigninButton } from 'react-native-google-signin';


<GoogleSigninButton
    style={{ width: 192, height: 48 }}
    size={GoogleSigninButton.Size.Wide}
    color={GoogleSigninButton.Color.Dark}
    onPress={signInWithGoogle}
     />
```

my package JSON below:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^10.0.6",
    "@react-native-community/google-signin": "^3.0.4",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.5",
    "expo": "~36.0.0",
    "expo-facebook": "~8.0.0",
    "expo-google-app-auth": "^8.0.1",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.5.0",
    "react-native-google-signin": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-link": "^4.1.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^3.6.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.4.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "0.6.0",
    "react-native-screens": "2.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native-status-bar-height": "^2.4.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-native-webview": "^8.1.2",
    "react-navigation": "^4.2.2",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.2.2",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.8.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.0.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: can you take a look at this [link](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/google-sign-in/) regarding the use of google-sign-in module for expo apps? it should help.